# Render a dynamic list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array of `books` in my redux store.

My reactjs component iterate over this like so `(books.map=>(book=>{...renderbook}))` to render the book.

So far so good.

Now when a new element is added to the `books` the entire list is being re-rendered. Is there a way in which this can be avoided? I believe 'ListView' does something similar in React-Native. Is there an equivalent in React-JS?

Comment: Sure `books.map(book => <Book>)`.

Comment: use keys https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the key property for each book:

```
books.map(book => <Book key={book.id} />);
```

If a book with an ID hasn't changed, they will not be re-rendered.

For more information on this, see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

More info here as well: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Comment: @Aditya Your edit actually goes expressly against the docs: `We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.`

Comment: Ohh! I didn't knew that. Thank you for explaining, makes sense. What if there isn't any unique identifier?

Comment: Then you should attach one, or create one based on unique elements in the object (Like `book.title+book.description`)